# When should you use "Title Case"?

Tags: writing, writing-style

Are there any guidelines for when you should capitalize titles/headings or not? Should you always do this in English?

I am referring to

**A Capitalized Heading**

vs

**A capitalized heading**

Answer (score 6):

The *title* of a book, play, movie, etc. should be capitalized as in your first example. Exceptions would be where the author, for artistic or other reasons, has specifically eschewed capitalization.

A *heading* or subheading, as in a section of an article, is different. In most cases the preference is to capitalize as in your second example--the editors I know and work with pretty uniformly object to anything but an initial capital letter in heads and subheads.

Comment: I am writing a techical report. I guess that could qualify as an "article".

Comment: The key, I think, is whether you're talking about the name of the report or the name of a subsection of it. The name of the report should be title case (first example) unless you have a darn good reason not to do that. The subsection headings WITHIN the report should only have sentence-style capitalization (second example).

Comment: I was referring to the headings within the report. It did not occur to me that the title itself could be different.

Comment: Is it true that "title case" is used in the US but not Britain?

Answer (score 3):

This is really a question of style.  A title is a title, but some titles are more important than others. For example, in a book the chapter titles are often title-case. If this is a document for your work, check for a style guide recommended by your workplace. If you are submitting it to a publisher such as a magazine, ask them. If there are no guidelines in place, I'd suggest deciding how important the headings are (as important as chapter titles in a novel?) and pick a consistent pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a style guide your organization subscribes to, look in that. Otherwise, do what you think is right.

Examples of style guides:

- [MLA](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/01/)
- [APA](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/section/2/10/)
- [AP](http://www.apstylebook.com/)

Comment: +1 whatever your readers (i.e., the group of people to or for whom you are writing) are accustomed to.

Comment: Would be good to have a summary of what those three style guides above have to say about usage of title case