# Plaque wording - capitalization?

Tags: capitalization

Language on a presentation plaque - is it written in sentence format or are the words capitalized like in a title? Example below:

In Recognition Of Your Exceptional Leadership Of The Prevention Program Of The Oregon Sexual Assault Task Force And Your Commitment To And Support Of The Effective Prevention Of And Response To Sexual Violence In Oregon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Name for this Style of Capitalisation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21019/is-there-a-name-for-this-style-of-capitalisation). That one asks what it's *called* (title case), but I think it answers OP's question here anyway.

Comment: The only thing it doesn't answer is whether a plaque should be in title case.

Comment: [Commemorative plaques](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=commemorative+plaque&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=adj&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=6gBZT6LcA5HV8QPY6IXjDg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CGwQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=940&sei=6wBZT5SaN9HR8QOThu22Cw)

Comment: Or [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized). I don't see how ELU can pronounce on whether any given plaque inscription should be capitalised or not - that's a free choice for the people commissioning it. But if it *is* capitalised, it would probably be a mistake to capitalise words like "and", as cornbread ninja says.

Comment: @MattЭллен: Looks like ALL CAPS is popular.  No more trying to figure out which words to capitalize.

Comment: @Danielδ yep! all letters are equally important :D

Answer (score 2):

This should be in sentence format.  It is worth noting that in title format, some words (such as *to*, *a*, *and*) are never capitalized.

My suggestion:

> In recognition of your exceptional leadership of the Prevention
>   Program of the Oregon Sexual Assault Task Force and of your commitment to
>   and support of the effective prevention of and response to sexual
>   violence in Oregon.

Comment: +1 *To* and *and* aren't articles, but everything else is perfect.  See [Which words in a title should be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14/10041)

Comment: color me embarrassed!  (a blue shade, please)